# How to select data source programmatically for XtraPivotGrid (Devexpress)

Tags: c#, devexpress

Firstly, I created an excel file with 2 columns and 20 rows. I turned it into a table. I tried this code in Visual Studio:

```
ExcelDataSource myExcelSource = new ExcelDataSource();
        myExcelSource.FileName = @"C:\Users\Fardin\Desktop\Book1.xlsx";
        ExcelWorksheetSettings worksheetSettings = new ExcelWorksheetSettings("Sheet1", "A1:B20");
        myExcelSource.SourceOptions = new ExcelSourceOptions(worksheetSettings);
        myExcelSource.SourceOptions.SkipEmptyRows = false;
        myExcelSource.SourceOptions.UseFirstRowAsHeader = true;
        myExcelSource.Fill();
        pivotGridControl1.DataSource = myExcelSource;
```

But, I have runtime error at last line. It says:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: What is null? myExcelSource, pivotGridControl1 or sth else?

Comment: pivotGridControl1 was null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  pivotGridControl1 is null it means you are missing this DevExpress control instance on your windows form (I assumed you are using WinForms). Drag and drop DevExpress PivotGridControl on your form and make sure you have entered correct control Name/Id.

Try to have a closer look at these two articles.:

**Binding to Excel Data Sources**

https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/115529/common-features/data-binding/binding-to-excel-data-sources

**How to: Create the Fields and Bind the PivotGridControl to a Excel Data Source**
https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/1921/controls-and-libraries/pivot-grid/examples/providing-data/how-to-bind-a-pivotgridcontrol-to-a-database